# Optimizing PHP Code

Tags: php

Is there a way to optimize this?

```
// Zählt die Anzahl an KWs
$sum = 0;
for ($i = 1; $i < 105; $i++) {
    $count = db_query('SELECT cw' . $i . ' FROM `prefix_projekteStep` WHERE kategoryid = ' . $row->id . ' AND id = ' . $rowStep->id.' AND jahr = '.$currentYear.' OR jahr = '.$nextYear.'');
    while ($rowStepC = db_fetch_object($count)) {
        $var = "cw" . $i;
        if ($rowStepC->$var === 1) {
            $sum += 1;
        }
    }
}    
echo $sum;
```

At the moment the script runs about 104 times in a call and I call this about 40 times. It takes very long to finish.

Comment: It appears you have 104 columns named `cw1` through `cw104`. Why execute the same query for each column? Why not one query with all 104 columns in the select column list?

Comment: What is this code attempting to *do* and *why*?  Several dozen trips to the database to perform a single operation seems *a bit* excessive.

Comment: If you could explain what you are trying to calculate, I suspect this could be done with one SQL statement.

Comment: You may also be able to take advantage of SQL aggregate functions (e.g. `SUM`) in order to avoid the inner loop. I think you could probably do this with a single query and no loops, though as others noted its not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It schould count how many of the 104 colums have an entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly the database structure is a poor design, so fixing that should be a priority.

Also, without a higher level understanding of what you are trying to achieve its hard to give a comprehensive answer, however given the info that can be gleaned from the code in your question, you could certainly just switch the loops, selecting the entire row in your sql and calculate the sum in a nested php loop, reducing your queries to 1:

```
$count = db_query('SELECT * FROM `prefix_projekteStep` WHERE kategoryid = ' . $row->id . ' AND id = ' . $rowStep->id.' AND jahr = '.$currentYear.' OR jahr = '.$nextYear.'');

while ($rowStepC = db_fetch_object($count)) {
     for ($i = 1; $i < 105; $i++) {
         $var = "cw" . $i;
         if ($rowStepC->$var === 1) {
               $sum += 1;
         }
     }
}
```

But refactoring the database should be considered a priority.

Comment: Yes the structure is bad thats right, will fix that .. its not my database  haha

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do, this might work. Run it and echo the SQL statement to see what it might look like:

```
$qstr .= "SELECT \n";
$cols = array();
for($i=1;$i<105;$i++) {
    $cols[$i] .= "IF(NOT `cw".$i."` IS NULL,1,0)";
}
$qstr .= implode(' + ',$cols)." AS `totalscore`, \n";
$qstr .= "FROM `prefix_projekteStep` \n";
$qstr .= "WHERE kategoryid = " . $row->id . " AND id = " . $rowStep->id." AND jahr = ".$currentYear." OR jahr = ".$nextYear."\n";

ECHO "<p>Query:<pre>".$qstr."</pre></p>\n";
```